# JavaScript, Understanding Query Strings

Tags: javascript, uri, query-string

I am trying to comprehend how query strings work.  I understand that values can be passed through the URL by using question marks and "&" signs to separate the values from the base URI.  For example: www.example.html?value1&value2

I have successfully used the following function shown below, but I am having a hard time understanding what is actually going on and I can't find much information about it.  If someone could give me an explanation on whats happening in this code, it would be very much appreciated!

```
        function getParameterByName(value) {
        value = value.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + value + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is using Regular Expressions to parse the string. You can learn more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!